# How to create an xml file in java and append data into it from user input

Tags: java, xml, append

I have created the xml file but problem is the when I am adding additional data it is being overwritten..I need a code which creates a new xml file if it doesnt exist or append to a xml file if it does exit...I am creating a log file which keeps the record of transactions

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import org.w3c.dom.DOMException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

 public class Log_XML {

  static String transaction_type, shop_no, terminal_no;

  static int id = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DOMException {
    System.out.println("Enter Id : ");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    id = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    System.out.println("Enter Transaction type : ");
    transaction_type = br.readLine();

    System.out.println("Shop no : ");
    shop_no = br.readLine();

    System.out.println(“Terminal no : “);
    terminal_no = br.readLine();
     write_XML_File(id);
   }

   public static void write_XML_File(int id) {
      String id_val = Integer.toString(id);
      try {
         DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

         Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();

         Element log1 = doc.createElement("log");
         doc.appendChild(log1);

         Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
         attr.setValue(id_val);
         log1.setAttributeNode(attr);

         Element transaction_type1 = doc.createElement("transaction_type");
         transaction_type1.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(transaction_type));
         log1.appendChild(transaction_type1);

         Element shop_no1 = doc.createElement("shop_no");
         shop_no1.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(shop_no));
         log1.appendChild(shop_no1);

         Element terminal_no1 = doc.createElement("terminal_no");
         terminal_no1.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(terminal_no));
         log1.appendChild(terminal_no1);

          TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
          Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
           transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
           DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
           StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("D:/log_file.xml"));
           transformer.transform(source, result);

           System.out.println("File saved!");
           } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TransformerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, XML is not designed to be appended, because it is seen as a tree with a root element. Something like:

```
<MyRoot>
<innerEll/>
</Myroot>
```

Once  is written you cannot append anything, in that case the solution is as in previous post : reRead it, add your new log.... but I don't think it will performm well!

If you decided to use a file with XML syntax but without the Root node, something like

```
<log> .... </log>
<log> .... </log>
```

you can then create the StreamResult from a StringWriter instead of a file. Then you can get the string from the StringWriter and use standard File api to append the string.

Note that you may have to "filter out" the string of some Xml declaration that can be before your main node.

Alternatively if the XML you want to generate is quite simple it is often easier to do it by hand:

```
myXML = "<log><Id>" + escapeXML(myId) + "</Id>...
```

escapeXML function is needed in case you have things like "<" in your string. There are many libraries to do this (or you can implement a simple thing adapted to your strings). Alternatively you can use CDATA if it gets too complicated.

Comment: I want to create a file with xml syntax without the root node like the second option that you wrote
      <log> .... </log>
      <log> .... </log>
So the next set of data will be inside the second log tags
Can you please show me the way to use StreamResult from a StringWriter to achieve this
I am new to this and I am stuck really bad
If you can help me out with the code it will be mighty helpfull

Thanks a lot in advance !!!

Comment: I have changed the code using StreamResult now the error shows:

XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
Location: file:///D:/log_file.xml
Line Number 17, Column 1:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
^

How to filter out this ?

Thanks again for your help !!!

Answer (score 1):

If the file exists: parse it, append new content at the appropriate location.

If it doesn't: do what you're doing now.

I'd re-use the appending code by either: creating a DOM and appending the new content as mentioned earlier, or by keeping a DOM shell file in the jar as a resource and using it as a default document.